# Unit Test on method with .setText()

Tags: android, unit-testing

I try to unit test a method in my android project.
Everything works unit I try to set a value on a TextView.
Is it possible to skip one line of code or do I have to implement it as a UI Test?

This is the method I try to test:

```
public int compareEnteredValue(int batterySize, double valueFromEntry, double batteryArray[]) {
    int output = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= batteryArray.length - 1; i++) {
        if (valueFromEntry >= batteryArray[i]) {
            realChargeValue.setText((i * 5) + ""); // This is where the unit test fails
            output = i*5;
        }
        if (valueFromEntry < batteryArray[batteryArray.length - 1]) {
            realChargeValue.setText(R.string.hundredPercent);
            output = 100;
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to mock TextView and method setText?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could break it down further. So that your unit does not set the text from within.

```
public int compareEnteredValue(int batterySize, double valueFromEntry, double batteryArray[]) {
    int output = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= batteryArray.length - 1; i++) {
        if (valueFromEntry >= batteryArray[i]) {
            //realChargeValue.setText((i * 5) + ""); // This is where the unit test fails
            output = i*5;
        }
        if (valueFromEntry < batteryArray[batteryArray.length - 1]) {
            //realChargeValue.setText(R.string.hundredPercent);
            output = 100;
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Then where you call the method..

```
 int value = compareEnteredValue(....);
 if(value == 100)
    realChargeValue.setText(R.string.hundredPercent);
 else 
    realChargeValue.setText(value + "");
```

You can then test the unit with no issue of the setText.

Comment: I don't know why but this doesn't work. The compareEnteredValue method is called by a setOnFocusChangeListener() If I try to setText in the listener after calling compareEnteredValue the value is always 100 EDIT: I fixed it. You have to set return output = i*5; and return output = 100;

Comment: @WeSt I was going to mention that your looping was a bit odd but didn't know for sure what you were trying to achieve. I guess that's the whole point in unit tests. It would identify that the return value was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Doomsknight answer, it is usually not required to Unit test every single line of your code. But in case you are passionate enough to test even to that level, here is how you can achieve it. I am using some added interfaces to showcase the testing.

```
public class TestableClass{
    private UIElement realChargeValue;

    public TestableClass(UIElement uiElem){
        realChargeValue = uiElem;
    }

    public int compareEnteredValue(int batterySize, double valueFromEntry, double batteryArray[]) {
        //Your method which needs to test realChargeValue

        int output = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= batteryArray.length - 1; i++) {
            if (valueFromEntry >= batteryArray[i]) {
                realChargeValue.setText((i * 5) + ""); // This is where the unit test fails
                output = i*5;
            }
            if (valueFromEntry < batteryArray[batteryArray.length - 1]) {
                realChargeValue.setText(R.string.hundredPercent);
                output = 100;
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
}

public interface UIElement{
    boolean setText();
}
```

For test class, you use as follows:

```
public class Test{
    @Test
    public void verify_compareEnteredValue_sets_correct_text(){
        ArgumentCaptor<String> argumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
        UIElement dummyUIElement = mock(UIElement.class);
        doReturn(true).when(dummyUIElement).setText(argumentCaptor.capture());

        new TestableClass(dummyUIElement).compareEnteredValue();

        List<String> expectedValues = argumentCaptor.getAllValues();
        //do all asserts here over expectedValues
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, Doomsknight answer was easy and made the job. But this could help me in the future too :)